# Redirect from parallel interceptor doesn't work when calling from server actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

## Description

Encountering an issue with interceptor redirection within the application flow. The problem arises when initiating the interceptor from the root path ('/') and navigating to '/join'. Upon clicking the 'Test' button, which triggers a server action designed to redirect back to the root ('/'), the expected redirection doesn't occur.

https://bitbucket.org/khoteiv/next-interceptor/src/main

Version: Next.js 14

### Steps to Reproduce

#### Access the Root ('/') Path:

Open the application at the root path.

#### Navigate to 'Join':

Click on the 'Join' link within the application.

#### Interceptor Occurrence:

Observe that an interceptor appears upon reaching the '/join' path.

#### Trigger Redirection via Server Action:

Click the 'Test' button, intended to redirect back to the root ('/').

#### Observation Post-Redirection:

Notice that despite the intended redirection, the application interface remains on the '/join' path instead of returning to the root ('/').